# addEventListener not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, event-listener

So I have a div which has an EventListener on it which works fine. But I want the EventListener to only be triggered at certain points, which is why I added an if statement to it.

I was under the impression that you can change global variables from functions the way my code is below yet this doesn't seem to work at all. I have tried changing the variable within the function by way of `window.clickDisable = false;` but that does not work either. The relevant parts of the code are below, does anybody know why this is not working? Thanks.

```
var clickDisable = true;

if (clickDisable == false) {
  document.getElementById("fight")
  var fightMenu = fight.addEventListener("click", fightMenuFunction)
}

function fightMenuFunction () {

}

setTimeout(introAnimation, 7000)
  function introAnimation() {
    clickDisable = false;
}
```

Comment: Your `clickDisable` variables stops adding the event listener, a better place might be to add it inside your event listener

Comment: The code never gets invoked again. You should add the eventListener after 7 seconds. Also fight is not defined in this example.

Comment: You *can* change global variables like this, but if statements that were previously false aren't magically re-run again with the new values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a handful of problems with your code:
I think the best approach is to put your if statement within the body of the function. You want the body of your function to run only if the timer has elapsed, rather than the event to be bound only if the timer has elapsed.

Also, your document.getElementById was not being used. You were instead benefiting from the fact that element ids are automatically interpreted as global variables, which you can do, as I have done below, but is probably not a best practice.

```js
var clickDisable = true;

function fightMenuFunction () {
  if(!clickDisable){
    console.log('This is the function running.')
  }
}
fight.addEventListener("click", fightMenuFunction)


window.setTimeout(introAnimation, 7000)
  function introAnimation() {
    clickDisable = false;
}
```

```html
<button id="fight">Fight</button>
```